# django: send an email with username and password information

Tags: django

I want to create username and password when I press on submit button of registration form. Where full name of user is entered by the user. And then username and password should be sent to the user.

Can anyone suggest how to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation on creating a user at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#creating-users and the documentation on sending an email at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/email/ .

It's basically just a matter of creating a form, writing a view to render it, and if the form is valid, create the user using that data and send the email off.